# One jquery code issue

Tags: jquery, css

my div is showing when it is hidden. i check lots of condition before shaking the div. my div's visibility is false but still it is showing with shake effect. here is whole code.

HTML:

```
<div id="EnableCookie" runat="server" class="cookieMsg">
    Please enable your browser cookie and refresh the page to view BBA Web site. 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cookieMsg {
    color: black;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 2% 25%;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    background: white;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
var isShaking = false;
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        if (!isShaking) {
            if (!$('#<% =EnableCookie.ClientID %>').css('display') != 'none') {
                if ($('#<% =EnableCookie.ClientID %>').length > 0) {
                    isShaking = true;
                    $('#<% =EnableCookie.ClientID %>').effect('shake', 200, function () { 
                        isShaking = false; 
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }, 3000);
});
```

My div is not supposed to show but it is showing, where have I made a mistake?

Comment: You have HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code all bunched together in one code block without their logical separators (e.g. `<style>` or `<script>`). Is that how you have it on your page? If not, can you show us how you do have it on your page? Can you also replace the `<% = %>` JSP tags with the values rendered to the markup (you can obtain this by right-clicking the page in a browser and choosing "View Source")?

Comment: @ajp15243 I think (and hope) the OP posted the code in one code block without split it in its composing part

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward I hope so too, and you're probably right, but I think it best to be as crystal clear as possible on the Internet for topics where detail matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test:

```
if (!$('#EnableCookie').css('display') != 'none') {
```

is meaning not is not displayed, so it's displayed.

Change your code to:

```
if ($('#EnableCookie').css('display') != 'none') {
```

or to:

```
if ($('#EnableCookie').is('visible')) {
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LrGNV/

Comment: i check your js fiddle code and it is working when i paste that code in my IDE but just do not understand what was wrong in my code because both the code looks similar. So just give me the hint what was the difference in code. thanks

Comment: @Thomas the issue is related to the double not in the test: __if(not display different from none)__ is like say __if(display is hidden)__ so remove the first not; if you need more info I'm here :-)